# JavaScript - Dúvida ao manipular valores de div's com variáveis

Tags: javascript, css, html5, drag-n-drop

Boa tarde ! 
Estou com uma dúvida em relação a manipulação de valores de div's...
Ao arrastar uma imagem da div `fundo1` (azul) ou a `fundo2` (amarela) para div `conteudo`, gostaria que os valores presente dentro da div `fundo1` (ou `fundo2`)
fosse para o textbox como na imagem a seguir: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Se for a imagem da div azul, o textbox ficará com o valor 1 
Se for a imagem amarela, ficará com o valor 2. 
Estou com problemas ao reconhecer o valor da div `valorFundo1` (valor 1) e `valorFundo2` (valor 2) dentro das div's e apresenta-la no textbox

Perdão a ignorância qualquer coisa e obrigado !!

```js
//Drag'n Drop functions
var elementCounter = 0; // Para designar a ID do elemento dropado.

function allowDrop(ev) {
  if (ev.target.getAttribute("droppable") == "false") {
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none"; // dropping is not allowed
    ev.preventDefault();
  } else {
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all"; // drop it like it's hot
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
}


function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
}

function drop(ev, div) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var x = ev.clientX;
  var y = ev.clientY;
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
  var original = document.getElementById(data);
  var altura = document.getElementById("drag1").height;
  var largura = document.getElementById("drag1").width;
  var c = x - largura;
  var d = y - altura;
  copyimg.src = original.src;
  div.appendChild(copyimg);
  if (original.parentNode.id == "conteudo") {
    if (ev.target.tagName == "IMG") { // Se a imagem estiver dropando em uma imagem
      console.log(ev.target.tagName);
      original.parentNode.removeChild(original);
      copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
      copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 70) + "px;");
      copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    } else { // Se não, é porque a imagem está sendo dropada em uma div
      original.parentNode.removeChild(original);
      copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
      copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 50) + "px;");
      copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    }
  } else {
    if (ev.target.tagName == "DIV") { // Se a imagem está sendo movimentada dentro da div conteudo
      copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
      copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 50) + "px;");
      copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    } else { // Se não, é porque está sendo dropada na IMG
      console.log(ev.target.tagName);
      copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
      copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 70) + "px;");
      copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.conteudo-externo {
  width: 55%;
  height: 60%;
  z-index: 3;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

.conteudo {
  width: 320px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 5;
  background: blue;
  margin: 35px auto;
}

.img {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px background-position:center;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#fundo1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

#fundo2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}


}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Biblioetca JQuery -->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="conteudo-externo" id="conteudo-externo">
    <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div>
    <input id="totalizador" name="totalizador" class="text" size="1" type="text" readonly="true" value="0" maxlength="999999" style=";border:0px solid #fff" /> <br>
  </div>
  <div id="fundo1">
    <img id="drag1" src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" />
    <div id="valor1" class="valFundo1"> 1 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="fundo2">
    <img id="drag2" src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" />
    <div id="valor2" class="valFundo2"> 2 </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tanto faz se o drag cair dentro do circulo ou fora?

Comment: A parte vermelha de fora está como draggable="false", deixei para cair somente na parte azul (o que é interessante para nós)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso juntando duas linhas:

```
var valorOrigem = original.nextElementSibling.textContent;
div.nextElementSibling.value = Number(div.nextElementSibling.value) + Number(valorOrigem);
```

```js
//Drag'n Drop functions
var elementCounter = 0; // Para designar a ID do elemento dropado.

function allowDrop(ev) {
  if (ev.target.getAttribute("droppable") == "false") {
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none"; // dropping is not allowed
    ev.preventDefault();
  } else {
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all"; // drop it like it's hot
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
}


function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
}

function drop(ev, div) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var x = ev.clientX;
  var y = ev.clientY;
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var copyimg = document.createElement("img");
  var original = document.getElementById(data);
  var valorOrigem = original.nextElementSibling.textContent;
  div.nextElementSibling.value = Number(div.nextElementSibling.value) + Number(valorOrigem);
  var altura = document.getElementById("drag1").height;
  var largura = document.getElementById("drag1").width;
  var c = x - largura;
  var d = y - altura;
  copyimg.src = original.src;
  div.appendChild(copyimg);
  if (original.parentNode.id == "conteudo") {
    if (ev.target.tagName == "IMG") { // Se a imagem estiver dropando em uma imagem
      console.log(ev.target.tagName);
      original.parentNode.removeChild(original);
      copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
      copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 70) + "px;");
      copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    } else { // Se não, é porque a imagem está sendo dropada em uma div
      original.parentNode.removeChild(original);
      copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
      copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 50) + "px;");
      copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    }
  } else {
    if (ev.target.tagName == "DIV") { // Se a imagem está sendo movimentada dentro da div conteudo
      copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
      copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 50) + "px;");
      copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    } else { // Se não, é porque está sendo dropada na IMG
      console.log(ev.target.tagName);
      copyimg.id = "dropped_elem" + (++elementCounter);
      copyimg.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; top: " + (y - 50) + "px; left:" + (x - 70) + "px;");
      copyimg.setAttribute('draggable', true);
      copyimg.setAttribute('ondragstart', "drag(event)");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.conteudo-externo {
  width: 55%;
  height: 60%;
  z-index: 3;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

.conteudo {
  width: 320px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 5;
  background: blue;
  margin: 35px auto;
}

.img {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px background-position:center;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#fundo1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

#fundo2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}


}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Biblioetca JQuery -->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="conteudo-externo" id="conteudo-externo">
    <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div>
    <input id="totalizador" name="totalizador" class="text" size="1" type="text" readonly="true" value="0" maxlength="999999" style=";border:0px solid #fff" /> <br>
  </div>
  <div id="fundo1">
    <img id="drag1" src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" />
    <div id="valor1" class="valFundo1"> 1 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="fundo2">
    <img id="drag2" src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="" />
    <div id="valor2" class="valFundo2"> 2 </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Olhando para o código há muita repetição... isso pode ser feito com menos código.
Uma sugestão seria:

```js
//Drag'n Drop functions
var elementCounter = 0; // Para designar a ID do elemento dropado.
var originalElement;

function onDragOver(ev) {
  var isDroppable = ev.target.getAttribute("droppable") !== "false";
  ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = isDroppable ? "all" : "none";
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function onDragStart(ev) {
  originalElement = ev.target;
  ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(originalElement, 15, 15);
}

function getCoords(ev) {
  var mouseCoords = {
    x: ev.clientX,
    y: ev.clientY
  }
  return mouseCoords

}

function drop(ev) {
  var valorOrigem = originalElement.nextElementSibling.textContent;
  var input = ev.target.nextElementSibling;
  input.value = Number(input.value) + Number(valorOrigem);

  var clone = originalElement.cloneNode(true);
  var mouseCoords = getCoords(ev);
  clone.style.left = mouseCoords.x - 15 + 'px';
  clone.style.top = mouseCoords.y - 15 + 'px';
  ev.target.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
.conteudo-externo {
  width: 55%;
  height: 60%;
  z-index: 3;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

.conteudo {
  width: 320px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  z-index: 5;
  background: blue;
  margin: 35px auto;
}

.conteudo [draggable] {
  position: absolute;
}

.img {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px background-position:center;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#fundo1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

#fundo2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}


}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Biblioetca JQuery -->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="conteudo-externo" id="conteudo-externo">
    <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo" ondrop="drop(event, this)" ondragover="onDragOver(event)">
    </div>
    <input id="totalizador" name="totalizador" class="text" size="1" type="text" readonly="true" value="0" maxlength="999999" style=";border:0px solid #fff" /> <br>
  </div>

  <div id="fundo1">
    <img src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" alt="" />
    <div id="valor1" class="valFundo1"> 1 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="fundo2">
    <img src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/i/n/indistinguishable.png?2" draggable="true" ondragstart="onDragStart(event)" alt="" />
    <div id="valor2" class="valFundo2"> 2 </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Vou estudar o código !! 
Obrigado pela ajuda @Sergio !!

Comment: caso se o text estivesse fora da div conteudo, teria como eu atribuir o valor a ele mesmo assim??

Comment: @Sora sim, se for um elemento único na página podes dar-lhe um ID. Senão é procurar por relações no DOM por exemplo.

Comment: Tens como me dar um exemplo de atribuição por favor? eu atribui o id do text como Totalizador, porém ao executar o código, retorna um erro de valor nulo. Seria por getElementBy??

Comment: $(totalizador).setAttribute("value", valorOriginal); algo assim?

Comment: @Sora é um `input`? ou uma `div`?

Comment: O `input` totalizador vai receber o valor de uma `div` (valor1) separada, que está dentro de uma outra div (`fundo1`)

Comment: Minha dúvida é se o input estiver fora dessas div's apresentadas como conteúdo ou conteúdo externo... Suponhamos que ela esteja em uma outra div chamada `totalFoot`

Comment: @Sora se tens um elemento com ID podes usar `document.getElementById('a-id-do-element')`. Se fôr um `input` usas `.value`, se for uma `div` usas `.textContent`. Independentemente de onde esteja visto IDs serem únicos. Assim, para um `input` podias fazer: `document.getElementById('totalizador').value = 'novo valor';`

Comment: Aaaah, entendi, muito obrigado pela explicação !!! Tenha um ótimo dia @Sergio